# How to change appium version for Appium Desktop

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I have Appium Desktop 1.2.7 which uses Appium 1.7.1 I also have Appium Desktop 1.6.2 which uses Appium 1.8.1. I am using Mac High Sierra.
When I launch AD 1.6.2 from Documents folder, it gave me a warning to keep the AD 1.6.2 in Applications Folder, which I did.

Now the issue is AD 1.2.7 is informed me to move to Applications Folder, which I did.
When I launch AD 1.2.7, it now connects to Appium 1.8.1. How do I change AD to connect to Appium 1.7.1?
Reason I want to do this is because the Appium Desktop Inspector is not working correctly when launching app with AD 1.6.2 and Appium 1.8.1 nor AD 1.2.7 with Appium 1.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible from inside of the Appium Desktop app, but you can install Appium via command line and run sessions from that using the 'Custom Server' tab.